# Issue using scikit-learn and scipy in ipython notebook 1.1.0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am new to scipy , scikit-learn and I found ipython notebook to be the best way to manage the snippets along with the resulting graphs. But I am getting this error on one of my snippet.

```
from figures import plot_sgd_separator
plot_sgd_separator()
```

ImportError: libmkl_gf_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

If anyone is familiar with resolving this issue, please resolve this issue

Here is the Error Log to get more help

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-420e7408298a> in <module>()
      1 # Import the example plot from the figures directory
----> 2 from figures import plot_sgd_separator
      3 plot_sgd_separator()

/home/chitrank/Documents/ScipyIndiaMumbai/scikit-learn/scipydotin_2013/notebooks/figures/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from sgd_separator import plot_sgd_separator
      2 from linear_regression import plot_linear_regression
      3 from bias_variance import plot_bias_variance

/home/chitrank/Documents/ScipyIndiaMumbai/scikit-learn/scipydotin_2013/notebooks/figures/sgd_separator.py in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 3 from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
      4 from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py in <module>()
     10 # complete documentation.
     11 
---> 12 from .base import LinearRegression
     13 
     14 from .bayes import BayesianRidge, ARDRegression

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py in <module>()
     18 import numpy as np
     19 import scipy.sparse as sp
---> 20 from scipy import linalg
     21 from scipy import sparse
     22 

/home/chitrank/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py in <module>()
    145 from .linalg_version import linalg_version as __version__
    146 
--> 147 from .misc import *
    148 from .basic import *
    149 from .decomp import *

/home/chitrank/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/misc.py in <module>()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 from numpy.linalg import LinAlgError
----> 5 from . import blas
      6 
      7 __all__ = ['LinAlgError', 'norm']

/home/chitrank/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/blas.py in <module>()
    111 import numpy as _np
    112 
--> 113 from scipy.linalg import _fblas
    114 try:
    115     from scipy.linalg import _cblas

ImportError: libmkl_gf_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What os, and how did you install python/numpy/scipy/scklearn?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Linux OS) and I have installed the modules from the source `python setup.py build` and then `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Have you followed this http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html? It states you will require ATLAS + LAPACK or MKL (which is what your error message states).